# Stay in Haridwar or Rishikesh

Tags: india

I would like to become a [sadhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadhu). I am planning to go to Haridwar or Rishikesh, and stay in an ashram until [Kumbh Mela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumbh_Mela) (I have heard it’s easier to find a guru during this time.) The problem is I am a teenager and most ashrams have 18+ rules. It would really appreciate if someone could help me in finding an ashram, or a place to stay overall.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel as defined in the [help]